# Intelij, launching generated JAR file which has another JAR files causes SecurityException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, jar

I have created `gradle` java project with Intellij IDEA 15:

[image: project]

Then in my `build.gradle` I have added this lines of code to `dependencies` in order to work with my other JAR files

```
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
```

Then I open Artifcats settings and set my Manifest File location with Main class:
[image: artifacts]

My Manifest file has that kind of content:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: kz.ant.signer.Main
```

My Main Class has simple `Hello world` function in my `private static main` method

Then I generate my JAR file and try to launch it by console. It shows me this message:

```
no main manifest attribute, in signer.jar
```

Then I open this JAR file with archiver and write my Main class manually in order to launch it.

Then it throws to me this error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Resource.cachedInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Resource.getByteBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

I think this happens because there are `*.RSA` and  `*.DSA` files inside Manifest's folder, so then I have added these lines of code in my `build.gradle`:

```
jar {
   doFirst {
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    }
   exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'
}
```

However, this does not change anything. There are still these signature files.

HOw to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you see the `*.RSA`, `*.SF` or `*.DSA` in the outputted jar?

Comment: @JBirdVegas Yes, even if I have added exclude lines in my gradle

Comment: What is the exact path you see them at?

Comment: @JBirdVegas inside META-INF folder